# Error with QtCreator configuration on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I've directed my students on the Windows platform to download QtCreator from

http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.0/qt-windows-opensource-5.2.0-mingw48_opengl-x86-offline.exe

This worked for all but two students. Here is a screenshot of their error, upon loading a test program:

[image: screenshot]

Here is the .pro file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2011-01-17T11:03:03
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui opengl

TARGET = lab0 TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    glwidget.cpp \
    objects.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    glwidget.h \
    objects.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

mac: INCLUDEPATH += -I/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework/Headers
mac: LIBS += -framework GLUT

unix:!macx:!symbian: INCLUDEPATH += -I/usr/X11R6/include
unix:!macx:!symbian: LIBS += -L/usr/X11R6/lib \
                                    -lGL -lglut

win32: INCLUDEPATH += C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\mingw48_32\include
win32: LIBS += libfreeglut
```

How do I debug this error?

Comment: Edit the question to show the contents of .pro file. The *exact* one they use, not whatever you gave them. The file must come from their system.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind at the moment is to reinstall Qt, perhaps from a fresh download.

Comment: Tried this already, though it occurs to me that I think this student had a weird setup between C:\ and D:\, I will investigate. Thanks.

Comment: i gues it should work without win32: INCLUDEPATH += C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\mingw48_32\include cause qmake can handle from the path.
And it is handy in the case that you provide .pro files to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there was a space in the path to the build folder. Removing said space fixed the build error.